# Google chrome sends an ogg file as webm

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, webm

im using mediaStreamRecorder to record a ogg file and send it to my API via Websocket and it is not compatible with WebM, it works fine in other browsers, but in chrome, my api says that the file is a webM, and throws an error.

this is part of my recorder.js file:

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
  if (audioarray.length>=2){
    var blob = new Blob(audioarray, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
    var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    blobsize  = blob.size;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onload = function(event){
      codedaudio = reader.result;
      console.log("File size: "+blobsize);
      audiourl = event.target.result;
      //cut Base64 code to the last ","
      audiomsg = codedaudio.substring(codedaudio.lastIndexOf(",")+1,codedaudio.length);
      console.log("Audio length: "+audioarray.length);
      sendMessage(audiomsg,'right','audio',blobURL);
      console.log("MediaStreamrecorder stopped");
      audioarray = [];
    };
  }else{
    // ToDo in short audio case
    console.log("audio is too short, it will not be sent")
    console.log("Audio length: "+audioarray.length);
    audioarray = [];
  };
}
```

here part of code that sends the ogg:

```
sendMessage = function (text,side,type,filepath) {
  webmessage = {
    message:text,
    type: type
  }
  message_side = side;
  //output debug
  if(text!=""){
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(webmessage));
    if (output==true){
      console.log(webmessage);
    }
  }
};
```

¿is there any way to send it as ogg on chrome?.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Firefox and possibly some other browsers, Chrome [doesn't support recording audio-only in an ogg container](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/fast/mediarecorder/MediaRecorder-isTypeSupported.html).

You can test the support with:

```
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/ogg")
```

Comment: Is there a way we could convert webm to ogg ?